# Cannot find class [com.etc.web.controller.HelloWorldController] for bean with name

Tags: spring-mvc

the error is "Cannot find class [com.etc.web.controller.HelloWorldController] for bean with name '/hello/world' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springMVC-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.etc.web.controller.HelloWorldController"

"com.etc.web.controller.HelloWorldController" is my own project struct.

I hava wrote bean in my springMVC-servlet.xml,bu it does not work.

the springMVC-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean name="/hello/world" class="com.etc.web.controller.HelloWorldController"></bean>

<bean id="" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="ViewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
     <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>springMVC1</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet- class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the error by build path—>Configure build path—>Source—>Default output folders for source folders.